# What are labels in Google Secret Manager for? What is their intended purpose?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I've got several different environments within a single project. By apparent design, they all must share a single, project-wide, Secret Manager namespace.

I thought labels might be a way to differentiate among secrets, either by allowing secrets with the same name but different labels (I do understand how improbable this notion is, given that it's essentially a K/V store), or by allowing the user to filter secrets using labels via an API call. No, not the case. In fact, the only parameters you can place on a listing of secrets regard *pagination*.

So what are labels used for in Secret Manager? How can they be accessed and leveraged programmatically?

Comment: Labels in Google Cloud are arbitrary user-supplied annotations that also appear in billing reports. You can perform filtering by labels on the client right now. In the coming weeks, you'll be able to do server-side filtering by labels.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like nowadays we can use labels to filter:

```
gcloud secrets list --project=<your project> --filter="labels.<label name>:<label value>
```

For example, if I have secrets with the label: `service: foo`, to get all secrets by this label I executed the following:

```
gcloud secrets list --project=<...> --filter="labels.service:foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Right now `gcloud` utility doesn't support any kind of filtering while listing secrets.**

Labels are part of the metadata of the project and as such form part of the possible secrets that are stored in the secret manager and for the moment only Console UI allows any filtering.

**However scripting comes to rescue and you can use this one-liner to do the dirty work:**

```
wb@cloudshell:~ (xxx)$ gcloud secrets list --format="flattened(name,labels)" | grep yes -A 2 -B 2
---
labels.lab1: yes
labels.lab2: 22
labels.lab3: abcd
wb@cloudshell:~ (xxx)$ gcloud secrets list --format="flattened(name,labels)" | grep abcd -A 2 -B 2
labels.lab1: yes
labels.lab2: 22
labels.lab3: abcd
name:        projects/544539236/secrets/sec1
---
```

As you can see the `list` output has been "flattened" to a name & format and then I used good old fashioned `grep` to do the work.

This one-liner is not perfect and picks up some lines that aren't needed or misses some but you can tweak it; you can even try `csv` format (instead of `flattened`) with combination of [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) to make the output coherent and more "presentable".

Also feel free to create a feature request on Google's IssueTracker and describe how you'd like to feature to work to save time in the future.

Similar question was also rised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044519/is-there-a-way-of-querying-google-secrets-manager).

You may also have a look at the documentation on [gcloud topics](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats) and [filtering & formating](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/it-ops/filtering-and-formatting-fun-with) it's output.

Also you may find [gcloud secrets list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/secrets/list) documentation useful.